# Wave Frequency and Penetration

Tags: visible-light, waves, frequency

Why are high frequency light waves highly penetrative, while low frequency sound waves are highly penetrative? 
Is there a general rule relating frequency and attenuation? And how does that differ for the different wave types?

Comment: The first part of your statement is not true in general so the question is not relevant. Radio waves (low energy) penetrate the walls of your house whereas light (high energy) does not.